# Installing Econometrics toolbox Matlab

Tags: macos, matlab

I want to install [this third-party toolbox](http://spatial-econometrics.com) for Matlab and I can't figure it out. I am using Matlab R2012a on OS X. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Figure what out? It appears to be a straightforward ZIP archive containing a bunch of M-files. You just need to make sure they're on your path. If you have a specific question, you should ask it.

Comment: I made sure that I installed it correctly as I do other MATLAB toolboxes, but I think there is a date issue as this toolbox was created in 1999, the book I am reading was published in 2006. I guess what I was really asking for was how to check if a certain toolbox is installed, which is not apparent from the question, the answer is to just type "ver" on the MATLAB command line